# Abstract Activity as base class for other activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this situation: an abstract activity and a series of activities that extend this one. The difference from parent activity is just a piece of layout, and some methods, how can I do with the layout? I declare 'n' very similar layout ? or I can only declare one and then extend only to the extent that change? and in this case, how?

I give you an example.

In MyAbstractActivity i call setContentView(R.layout.abstract_layout), where abstract_layout.xml has this layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Button id=1/>
    <Button id=2/>
    <Button id=3/>
    <Button id=4/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in MyConcreteActivity that extends MyAbstractActivity suppose that we want a textfield below Button with id=2, how we can do?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Solved using ViewStub in superclass and changing it in subclasses.

Comment: You could inflate the view in the subclass and then edit it and setContentView again

Comment: Unfortunately you can't call `setContentView` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a separate layout for each of your subclasses. Then in your subclass `onCreate` you could do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.concrete_layout_1);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

And avoid calling `setContentView` in your abstract activity. Depending on the code you currently have in `MyAbstractActivity#onCreate`, you may have some refactoring to do.

In the end there isn't really a concept of inheritance for layouts, although you can do some creative things with `<include ...>`; you might check [Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) if you care about [DRY](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: i solved declarin ViewStub in superclass and changing it in subclass

Comment: Hi Matthew. Just wondering why should we avoid calling `setContentView` on abstract activities. I was about to do just that when I found this question...

Comment: Here is an example of how to set the content views: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8821459/3681880