# Creating a Static Menu Bar

Tags: java, android, xml

What I've been trying to do is create a menu that stays "static" no matter what activity or layout is being showed. Is there any way to do this, or anything similar to this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

**1-** Create a custom Activity (extend it from Activity)

**2-** Write the code for menu creation in that custom Activty.

**3-** Now extend all your Activities from this custom Activity.

Comment: Is there any way to implement this with the tabwidget?

Comment: The TabWidget can be used inside ACTIVITY; So yes the above solution will work for you.

Comment: Any example that could help? I created an activity, created a button and added the button to the layout but nothing seems to happen when I extends the other activities from this activity...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821240/android-how-to-create-my-own-activity-and-extend-it