# Android - execute code onResume and onPause for all the activities of the app?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, onresume, onpause

I'm designing an architecture where the app needs to execute certain set of operations everytime it goes to background (onPause) and a set of operations everytime it comes back to foreground (onResume), irrespective of the activity (for all the activities). Is there a way with which I can achieve this, without having to call those methods in every activity class' onPause and onResume overrides?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your own class that extends `Activity` and add your desired behavior to its `onPause` and `onResume` methods.
Then you extend that class on your activities.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This gets called whenever the user switches activities, how can we make it get called only if the user has left the app?

Comment: @Rich for that, you should override `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 1):

You could extends your `Activities` by a `BaseActivity` which `extends Activity`, and create the two methods **onPause** / **onResume** in it.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8821459/2668136) for more information.