# How to implement same broadcast receiver across all activities

Tags: android

I have 4 screens in my application. Instead of declaring the bluetooth broadcast receiver for all 4 activites again and again, I would like to declare once and implement in all 4 activities. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Create an abstract activity called `AbstractActivity`. Make all other activities `extend` this abstract `Activity` and declare the BroadCast Receiver in that abstract activity. For knowing a bit more about it this question might help: [android how to create my own Activity and extend it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821240/android-how-to-create-my-own-activity-and-extend-it)