# Sharing the DataBase between Two Activities in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a DataBaseAdapter class, which basically creates the database, table and some methods to manipulate the data in it.

It looks like this-

```
import ...

public class DataBaseAdapter  {

    DataBaseForApp dataBaseForApp;
    //Constructor for DataBaseAdapter
    public DataBaseAdapter(Context context) {

    }
    //insert data
    public long insertData(String player_name,int enrollmentno)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDB=dataBaseForApp.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(dataBaseForApp.NAME,player_name);
        contentValues.put(dataBaseForApp.ENROL,enrollmentno);
        long id=SQLiteDB.insert(dataBaseForApp.DATABASE_TABLE,null,contentValues);
        SQLiteDB.close();
        return id;
    }
    //search for a player name and the square grid size
    public boolean search(String player_name, int enrollmentno)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDB=dataBaseForApp.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={dataBaseForApp.NAME,dataBaseForApp.ENROL};
        String[] arguments={player_name,Integer.toString(enrollmentno)};
        Cursor cursor=SQLiteDB.query(dataBaseForApp.DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            int index1=cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBaseForApp.NAME);
            int index2=cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBaseForApp.ENROL);
            String name=cursor.getString(index1);
            int gsize=cursor.getInt(index2);
            if(name.equals(player_name)&&gsize==enrollmentno)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        SQLiteDB.close();
        return false;

    }
    // main class
    static class DataBaseForApp extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="SQLiteDB_FOR_APP";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="INFO";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
        private static final String NAME="NAME";
        private static final String ENROL="ENROL";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("+NAME+" VARCHAR(100), "+ENROL+" INT)";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE;


        public DataBaseForApp(Context context) {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDB) {
            try {
                SQLiteDB.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                SQLiteDB.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(SQLiteDB);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then I did this in my First Activity-

```
DataBaseAdapter dataBaseAdapter=new DataBaseAdapter(ActivityOne.this);
```

After this, A database has been created and the methods in DataBaseAdapter are available to me for manipulation.

So far, It is cool, but problem arises when I want to get the same database for my second activity to insert the data from there.

If I use this-

```
 DataBaseAdapter dataBaseAdapter=new DataBaseAdapter(ActivityTwo.this);
```

then, it means I am trying to create the database once again.

Please suggest me how to share the database between two activities.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, your `DataBaseForApp` class is never instantiated. I Suppose you want this to be done in the `DataBaseAdapter` constructor.

Second, what you want to do is  have multiple instances of the `DataBaseForApp` (extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`) class. IMHO you don't need this. You could subclass the Application class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static DataBaseAdapter dbAdapter;

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDbAdapter() {
        return dbAdapter;
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate(); 
        dbAdapter = new DataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    } 
}
```

And in your manifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `abstract` `BaseActivity` which all other activities can extend. Inside the `BaseActivity` create an instance of the `DataBaseAdapter`. You'll be able to use this in all your activities. Here is an example : [android how to create my own Activity and extend it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821240/android-how-to-create-my-own-activity-and-extend-it)

You can use `BaseActivity` as a single place for the thing you need in all the activities. Eg:  `ProgressDialog` or `AlertDialog` etc.