# Android call class to multiple activities

Tags: android

I want to call my singleton class to my multiple activities in android with the use of extend. I am just confused how to connect class with multiple activities. I have one custom them class which I want to apply for multiple activities.

Comment: why you want to do this ??

Comment: Clear your question more.

Comment: If you want an abstract class to be implemented in multiple activities this would help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8821459/3690664