# How to use R.id conventionally in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I inherit all of my activities and fragments from base activity and base fragment.

I want to centralize some behaviors across applications and create some separate git repositories for them.

A convention is that each activity and fragment should have a main `ProgressBar` that is embedded inside XML layout anywhere, and its id is simply **progress**.

The problem is that the `ProgressBar` class is defined in another git repository, while the actual XML is defined in other git repositories. Thus I have no access to `R.id.progress` in my code.

In my `BaseActivity` I have this code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            progress = findViewById(R.id.progress); // this line is red
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // notifying error
        }
    }

    public void showProgress() {
        // showing progress
    }

    public void hideProgress() {
        // hiding
    }
}
```

So that in all of my activities I simply call `showProgress();` whenever I need to.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you included that other project in your project?

Comment: simply extend your baseactivity to other activities

Comment: @ReazMurshed, I'm referencing the `framework` project from `app1`, `app2`, etc. It's not the other way around. The problem is that my `framework` is not built stand-alone.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android how to create my own Activity and extend it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821240/android-how-to-create-my-own-activity-and-extend-it)

Comment: @Selvin, not helpful at all.

Comment: check resource types in official documentation

Comment: What's the package you have imported for `R`?

Comment: Is `R`'s package is main app's package or framework's package?

Comment: can you update the question to show the relationship between all the git repositories and your app? are they separate projects/modules or libraries? If I am reading you correctly, you want to re-use common xml that you have packaged into a separate module and added to your project?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I suspect you can't (at least, through any standard path) do this - resources for each app / library are kept separated from each other so that they don't conflict. It's probably *possible* to just use the ID, but hacky. I would recommend creating a XML element to hold the view, and the load it programmatically in your code into that view. If someone else knows how to do this, I'm curious how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `BaseActivity` is reside inside a base module (let's call `BaseActivity Module`) and the actual activity and xml is inside another module (let's call `Activity Module`) which is depends on BaseActivity module like this hierarchy:

```
 Activity Module
   -- BaseActivity module
```

Then you can create an xml file which contains `R.id.progress` in BaseActivity as a temporary id.

When you're using create a subclass from BaseActivity where the subclass activity has an xml containing `R.id.progress`. Your activity will use the `R.id.progress` from the xml instead from BaseActivity.

Please be noted that each xml with some specific name can be override by adding xml with the same name. For example, if you have `view_progress.xml` in BaseActivity module, it will be overridden by the `view_progress.xml` in Activity Module.

Comment: Now this is the answer. Great explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have that id in one of the layout files the ID will be generated inside the R file. Still probably a better idea to use an abstract class and method which then specify the id in subclasses:

```
abstract int getProgressBarId();
```

so then you can do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            int progressBarId = getProgressBarId();
            if(progressBarId != 0) {
                 progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
            } 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // notifying error
        }
    }
```

Comment: Layout files are in another project. The `BaseActivity` has no idea about the real `ProgressBar`. It just knows it has to be there by convention. And I don't want to implement that abstract method throughout my all activities. It's convention over configuration.

Comment: My other suggestion would be to look into Databinding. Then you dont need to use findViewById at all. Simply use an ObervableBoolean in your layout file and update the visibility of the Progressbar there. A much cleaner and modern approach.