# Is it possible to completely disable the back button in android application?

Tags: android

Is it possible to completely disable the back button in the entire android application and is it possible to do it individually?

[image: Back button image]

Here is a picture of back button that I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

For a single activity, you need to do the following

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (!shouldAllowBack()) {
       return;
   }
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

where `shouldAllowBack()` will have the logic whether back is allowed or not.

**For disabling it through out the application**, Just create a parent activity and extend from it in your other activities. Add the above code in the parent activity and you just need to return from `onBackPressed()` method. You can refer this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8821459/681929) to know that how to extend an activity.

Answer (score 3):

If you totally want to disable your back button, you can just override the `onBackPressed` on your `Activity` and Android will know when back button is pressed. So you can just return:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  return;
}
```

With doing it individually I hope you mean programmatically.